# Linked HTML 5 video from sub-domain not playing in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5-video, subdomain, video-player

I have a web app with my media files being uploaded to a sub-domain. The images are displaying well but NOT so for videos across all browsers, the files is not linked to the site and it shows MIME type not supported. Everything works well on localhost.

The video file URL is correct and can be downloaded from the browser, I have copied the video file to the main domain and it worked but trying to load it from the sub-domain is not going well at all.

Please what may be the cause of this and how can i overcome it? I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, IIS 8.0, MIME types are set.

[image: snapshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. I had set MIME types from my main domain but it still needed to be set on the sub-domain as well. After days of battling I just got it by trial.

[image]